# C - The code prints the text read from the text file weirdly with new line that do not exist

Tags: c, text, printing, malloc

the code reads a file and prints its contents

```
void printArray(Array* a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a->used; i++) {
        printf("---------------\n%d\n", a->array[i].id);
        printf("%s\n", a->array[i].title);
        printf("%s ", a->array[i].director->director_name);
        printf("%s\n", a->array[i].director->director_surname);
        printf("%d/", a->array[i].release_date->day);
        printf("%d/", a->array[i].release_date->month);
        printf("%d\n---------------\n", a->array[i].release_date->year);
    }
}
void readFile(Array* a)
{
    
    char str[20];
    FILE *f = fopen("C:\\(...)\\Movies.txt" , "r"); 
    if(f == NULL){
    perror("Error opening file"); // print error 
  }
  else{
    while(fgets(str, 20, f)){
      
    movie film;
    film.title = malloc(sizeof(film.title) * sizeof(char));
    film.director = malloc(sizeof(director_info) * sizeof(char));
    film.director->director_name = malloc(sizeof(film.director->director_name) * sizeof(char));
    film.director->director_surname = malloc(sizeof(film.director->director_surname));
    film.release_date = malloc(sizeof(film.release_date));
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size++;
        a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(movie));
    }
    film.id = atoi(str); 
    
    char* buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(buffer, 20, f);
    strcpy(film.title, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
    
    
    buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(buffer, 20, f);
    strcpy(film.director->director_surname, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
    
    buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(buffer, 20, f);
    strcpy(film.director->director_name, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
    
    fgets(str, 20, f);
    film.release_date->day = atoi(str); 
    fgets(str, 20, f);
    film.release_date->month = atoi(str); 
    fgets(str, 20, f);
    film.release_date->year = atoi(str); 
    a->array[a->used] = film;
    a->used++;
  }
  fclose(f);
}
}
```

the file Movies.txt has these movies inside
first the id, then the movie, director surname, director name, and date:

```
0
lord_of_the_rings
Jackson
Peter
19
12
2001
1
hobbit
Jackson
peter
14
12
2012
2
inception
nolan
christopher
24
8
2010
```

the printed movies shouldn't get an empty line in between, what's wrong?

Comment: You're probably not allocating enough space for all those struct members.

Comment: `sizeof(film.title)` is the size of a pointer, which is usually 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: All your allocations make this mistake.'

Comment: I see that some of your printf statements have \n at the end.  You read in the fields from the file using fgets, which stores the \n at the end of the string.  So my guess is you are printing a string that already has a \n with another \n in the printf call.

Comment: Also, I see that you malloc and free the same size buffer over and over.  You should just allocate it once and free it when you're done, or better yet since it's only 100 bytes just allocate it locally as char buffer[100].

Comment: fgets() keeps the "\r'n" in the buffer. You could strip this before using the buffer.